# I want to re-queue into RabbitMQ when there is error with added values to queue payload

Tags: node.js, typescript, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a peculiar type of problem statement to be solved.

Configured RabbitMQ as message broker and its working but when there is failure in process in consume I'm now acknowledging with *nack* but it blindly re-queues with whatever already came in as payload but i want to add some-more fields to it and re-queue with simpler steps

For Example:

When consume gets payload data from RabbitMQ it will then process it and try to do some process based on it in multiple host machines, but due to some thing if one machine not reachable i need to process that alone after some time .
Hence I'm planning to re-queue failed data with one more fields with *machine name* again back to queue so it will be processed again with existing logic itself.

How to achieve this ? Can someone help on me

Answer (score 2):

When a message is requeued, the message will be placed to its original position in its queue, if possible. If not (due to concurrent deliveries and acknowledgements from other consumers when multiple consumers share a queue), the message will be requeued to a position closer to queue head. This way you will end up in an infinite loop(consuming and requeuing the message). To avoid this, you can, positively acknowledge the message and publish it to the queue with the updated fields. Publishing the message puts it at the end of the queue, hence you will be able to process it after some time.

Reference https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

Comment: I too same kind of concept after getting into infinite loop  going with nack ! Thanks for suggesting me this!!